# Maximum Likelihood estimator with cubic function

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, ...,X_n$ independent sample variables of the random variable $X$. Show that the Maximum likelihood estimator $S$ for $\theta := \frac{1}{\lambda}$ is given by:

$$S = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^3}{n}$$

The exponential distribution is defined as:

$$f_X(x) = \lambda \cdot 3x^2 \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot x^3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for }  x \geq 0 $$

I tried everything this, but the derivation is still a problem.

$$(1) \  L (\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \lambda \cdot 3x_i^2 \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot x_i^3} = e^{-\lambda \cdot x_i^3} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda \cdot 3x_i^2$$
$$(2) \ \ \ln(L(\theta)) = -n^3 \cdot \lambda + \sum_{i = 1}^n ln(\lambda) \cdot ln(3x_i)^2$$

$$(3) \ \ ln'(L(\theta)) = - n^3 + \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda} \cdot \frac{1}{3x_i^2}  = 0$$

$$(4) \ \ \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{3x_i^2} = n^3$$

$$(5) \ \ \lambda = \frac{n^3}{\sum_{i = 1}^n 3x_i^2}$$

That's don't look like S above.

Would be glad, if someone has a hint.

Comment: What is $\lambda$? What is the distribution of $X$? What have you tried?

Comment: I just forgot to write the distribution, here it is

Comment: How did you take the exponential out of the product in the first step?  It contains the index i.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression rearranging the likelihood is not quite correct.

$$ L (\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \lambda \cdot 3x_i^2 \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot x_i^3} = \lambda^n  \cdot 3^n \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot \sum x_i^3} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n  x_i^2$$

$$\log_e(L(\theta)) = n \log_e(\lambda) + n \log_e(3) -\lambda  \sum x_i^3 + 2 \sum \log_e(x_i)$$

The rest you can probably do yourself

Comment: Thank you very much :), but why not ln?

Comment: @Bilbo_harman Because I am a mathematician not an Excel spreadsheet.  I have changed $\log$ to $\log_e$ for greater precision